# Update Ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10

Tags: updates, software-updater

If i update ubuntu from 13.04 to 13.10,

It will delete all the installed softwares..?

It will delete any of my data..?

I'm totally new to ubuntu.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All of your settings, files in your /home directory and personal software will be preserved.

It is recommended, however, to make a backup beforehand in case the update renders your operating system inoperable. The chance of this happening shouldn't be big.

Comment: Thanks man, so i'm good to go. Any tips..?

Comment: If this answered your question, please mark it as accepted by clicking the checkmark under the vote counter.

Comment: As for tips, don't touch your computer while its updating. It could mess things up.